# Cannot access Table in converted query (plain SQL to LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm trying to convert this working SQL query into a LINQ query (EF)

But in the LINQ query I can't get into the category data table.
This is my working  SQL Query:

```
SELECT cosmetics.brand, cosmetics.product, cosmetics.size, cosmetics.price, cosmetics.sale_type, cosmetics.description, cosmetics.date, cosmetics.company_id, cosmetics.category, cosmetics.[male-female], company.company_site 
FROM cosmetics INNER JOIN company ON cosmetics.company_id = company.company_id 
WHERE (cosmetics.date >= GETDATE()) 
    AND (cosmetics.[male-female] = N'female') 
    AND (cosmetics.category = N'cosmetics_perfumes') 
ORDER BY cosmetics.brand, cosmetics.product, cosmetics.size, cosmetics.price"
```

This is working just fine:

```
var female = (from c in db.cosmetics
                .Where(v => v.date > DateTime.Now)
                .Where(d => d.male_female == "female")
                .Include("company")
            select c);
return View(female.ToList());
```

Comment: Try using LINQPad as you will find it invaluable in a situation like this.

Comment: And find LINQpad [here](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: What is "the category data table"? In you working sql query there are only two tables used: cosmetics and company. There seems to be no "category data table" in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var q =
  from cos in oc.cosmetics
  join com in oc.company on cos.company_id equals com.company_id
  where cos.date >= DateTime.Now
     && cos.male_female == "female"
     && cos.category == "cosmetics_perfumes"
  orderby cos.brand, cos.product, cos.size, cos.price
  select new { cos, com.company_site };
```

Comment: thanks, using it i'm getting this Error in my view :The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[Sr_D.Models.cosmetic,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Sr_D.Models.cosmetic]'. my view is using this model:@model IEnumerable<Sr_D.Models.cosmetic> what did i do wrong here?

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, it look like this is working: var female=from c in db.cosmetics
                           .Where(s=>s.date>DateTime.Now)
                           .Include("company")
                           .Where(z=>z.category=="cosmetics_perfumes").Where(x=>x.male_female=="female")
                           select c;